# Flurry - Identifies more new users than downloads

Tags: ios, swift, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have an app that requires a Login. We launched 10 days ago.

The problem is: itunes connect says we have 40 downloads in total, and at the same time Flurry identifies 70+ new users.

This is how I have setup Flurry in the AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    Flurry.startSession("XXXXXXXX")

    if let userEmail = email{
        // user logged with our login
        println("User logged via ff.")
        Flurry.setUserID(userEmail as String)
    }else if let userID = id{
        // user logged with Facebook
        println("User logged with facebook.")
        Flurry.setUserID(userID as String)
    }else{
        // user not logged
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of discrepancy is usually caused by users with multiple devices.

Flurry counts user's by their device id (idfa), but iTunes counts multiple downloads by the same user as one download.

So this points to some user's with an iPhone and an iPad or who have upgraded their device. Also please make certain you are using the most recent SDK v6.3

Comment: For a user to have the app on both an iPhone and iPad, it would have counted as two downloads on iTunes Connect correct - this wouldn't have contributed to this discrepancy, would it?

Comment: Google and Apple's app store will identify a user based upon the email address they sign in with and will not double count installs for that user's devices.